# Java program to parse the output of group generated using Pig scripting

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I need to parse the following line using Java, which is generated as a result of Pig group function.

```
(D1,{(A1,null,C1,D1,E1),(null,B1,C1,D1,E1),(A2,null,null,D1,E2)})
```

Here D1 is the Key, and `(A1,null,C1,D1,E1),(null,B1,C1,D1,E1),(A2,null,null,D1,E2)` are the corresponding values.

I am looking for a java pgm to retain only the values. However split function on ',' cant be applied directly as the inner elements also contain , delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crappy DIY solution would be to first isolate `"(A1,null,C1,D1,E1),(null,B1,C1,D1,E1),(A2,null,null,D1,E2)"`, then split that on `"),("` so that you have `"(A1,null,C1,D1,E1"`, `"null,B1,C1,D1,E1"`, and `"A2,null,null,D1,E2)"`. Remove extraneous parentheses, and then  split on commas for each one as you wanted.